# Proof about hessian matrix and vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hessian-matrix

I would like some help with the following question:

Given a $ C^{2} $ function $ f:  \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} $ and $a \in  \mathbb{R}^n $, a local minima point of $f$, and $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ a vector.

Show that $$v^T \cdot H_{f}(a) \cdot v \ge 0 $$

Also show that all the eigenvalues of $H_{f}(a)$ are non-negative, where $H_f$ is the Hessian of $f$.

I was given a hint that I should use Taylor expansion for  $g(t)=f(a+vt)$

Any insight about this question will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the $C^2$ condition you are entitled to expand $f$ around this local minima (say $x_0$) as:
$$f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)=\nabla f|_{x_0}\cdot h+\frac12h^TH_fh+o(\|h\|^2)$$
at least for small $h\in\Bbb R^2$. However, due to differentiability $\nabla f|_{x_0}$ vanishes, so the RHS becomes $\frac12h^TH_fh+o(\|h\|^2)$.

Note that $H_f$ is symmetric, we can find an orthogonal $Q$ such that $H_f=Q^T\Lambda Q$ in which $\Lambda$ is the eigenvalue matrix of $H_f$, so that if we let $\eta:=Qh$
$$f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)=\frac12h^TH_fh+o(\|h\|^2)=\frac12\eta^T\Lambda\eta + o(\|\eta\|^2)=\frac12\sum_1^n\lambda_i\eta_i^2 + o(\|\eta\|^2).$$
Now suppose there is some $\lambda_i$, say $\lambda_1<0$, then choose $\eta=te_1$, and we have
$$f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)=\frac12\lambda_1t^2+o(t^2)<0$$
for $t$ sufficiently small, contradicting that $x_0$ is a local minimum.

Comment: Assuming all eigenvalues are positive and thus the Hessian is positive definite, what guarantees that RHS>LHS given the rest term? Thanks.

Comment: @user996159 I think the question is to *prove* the Hessian is PSD. In my answer I used proof by contradiction i.e. *assumed* first that $H_f$ is *not* PSD and thus there exists a strictly negative eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ pertinent to $H_f$, and then showed the existence of $\lambda_1$ would contradict the condition that $x_0$ is a local minimum.

Comment: I do not know what by PSD is meant. In my question I assumed that all eigenvalues are positive. Starting from here, I do not know how to handle the rest, o(\|\eta\|^2), in proving $f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) > 0.$ It is clear that the quadratic form is positive but the rest term might be negative. So, how can one show that $\frac12\sum_1^n\lambda_i\eta_i^2 + o(\|\eta\|^2) > 0$ for $\|h\|$ sufficiently small ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apply Taylor expansion. The gradient term will be zero because of the necessary condition. Next, argue $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} g(t) \geq g(0)$ for any unit vector $v$.